# IR Remote - Working with RPi2, not with Pi Zero Wireless

Tags: pwm, lirc

I have a frustrating problem here.  Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on what the issue might be.  I'm building an IR remote with RPis.

I built the first one with RPi2 and got it to work with no problems.  I decided to buy another Pi Zero Wireless for the final implementation because it's easier to place near equipment that uses old-fashioned IR remotes.  I set up the new pi0w the same way, and transferred the wires on the RPi2 to the pi0w, leaving everything on the protoboard untouched.  It doesn't work with the pi0w.  I connected it to a visible LED and issued a send command, and I saw the LED blink.  I also saw the IR LED blink after issuing a command through an IR security camera that I have.  However, it fails to operate a nearby device.  I switched back to the RPi2 and it's still working.

Any thoughts on what might be the problem with the pi0w?  It was a few months between setting up the two, so maybe I missed a step?  But since the LED is lighting, I'd expect it to be working.

Comment: Different power supply?  Software timing of pulses different between Pi2 and Zero?

Comment: This may be obvious, but you don't explicitly state it in your question, did the old setup work with the same device?

Comment: Using same power supply for both RPis and (attempting) to control the same device with them, a nearby LED strip.  Proximity of IR LED to device is identical.  Maybe later I'll try to setup the RPi2 to read the signal, and the pi0w to send, and see if I can read what I think is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back to this project and figured out a solution.  I was using the same lircd.conf file on both the rpi2 and the rpi0w.  I created this file recording signals from remote controls on the rpi2.  I had to make a new lircd.conf file on the rpi0w by recording the remote control signals again on the rpi0w.  The differences were minor, but that's how I finally got it to work.